# "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'" after changing Min Sdk Version?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I recently changed the Min Sdk Version from kitkat to lollipop via the project structure settings, now with every reference to an XML resource within a java file, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'".

I'm not sure what other relevant info I can give as that literally the only change I've made.

The error I get in the gradle build is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Clean/Rebuild is not solving the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cleaning the project usually helps in these situations. If it doesn't, you should try to run `gradle --info assembleDebug` from the command line to get more information about why the build process is failing.

Comment: make sure you already installed the build tool for the target Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for these problem is to :

Click on **Build** -> **Rebuild** Project and then click **Tools** -> **Android** -> **Sync Project with Gradle Files**.

Comment: Ah, it turns out I had made some errors in the manifest, this did help me find that however, thanks!